# ElasticSearch how to set specific index for a QueryBuilder (Java API)

Tags: java, kotlin, elasticsearch, curl, query-builder

I'm trying to convert this multiple **GET** operation of elasticsearch into the *Java/Kotlin* code equivalent

```
curl "localhost:9200/index1, index2/_search?pretty=true" -d '{
    "query" : {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : [
                {
                    "indices" : {
                        "indices" : ["index1"],
                        "query" : {
                            SOMETHING1
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "indices" : {
                        "indices" : ["index2"],
                        "query" : {
                            SOMETHING2
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}'
```

My solution is

```
val searchRequest = SearchRequest("index1", "index2")
val searchSourceBuilder = SearchSourceBuilder()
val qb: BoolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()

val qbFirst: BoolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
qbFirst.must().add(SOMETHING1)

val qbSecond: BoolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
qbSecond.must().add(SOMETHING2)

qb.must().add(qbFirst)
qb.must().add(qbSecond)

searchSourceBuilder.query(qb)
searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder)
```

It's not so important the *SOMETHING1* and *SOMETHING2* code block.
The problem of my solution is that I can't be able to specify for `qbFirst` to consider *ONLY* *index1* for the research. Unfortunately it uses both *index1* and *index2* (and the same for qbSecond)
Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is the following:

```
val qb: BoolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
var q1: XXXBuilder = QueryBuilders.xxxQuery()
var q2: XXXBuilder = QueryBuilders.xxxQuery()

qb.must().add(QueryBuilders.indicesQuery(q1, "index1"))
qb.must().add(QueryBuilders.indicesQuery(q2, "index2"))
```

Now, since the `indices` query has been [deprecated in ES 5](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/query-dsl-indices-query.html) and removed in ES 6, if you ever upgrade, you'll need to search on the `_index` field instead, which goes like this:

```
val qb: BoolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()

var q1: BoolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
q1.must().add(QueryBuilders.termQuery("_index", "index1"))
q1.must().add(QueryBuilders.xxxQuery("SOMETHING1"))

var q2: BoolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
q2.must().add(QueryBuilders.termQuery("_index", "index2"))
q2.must().add(QueryBuilders.xxxQuery("SOMETHING2"))

qb.must().add(q1)
qb.must().add(q2)
```

PS: also note that unless you have a document that is present in both indexes at the same time and satisfies both conditions, you should be using `should` instead of `must` in the top-level query.

Comment: Perfect answer! Thanks a lot